# Populating a ComboBox using a filter

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a database with the following columns:

```
RegNumber | LastName | FirstName | OOPVB | DataComms | ModelsDB | MAB | OB | CF
```

I want to populate a ComboBox with columns `OOPVB,DataComms,ModelsDB,MAB,OB` and `CF`.

I have only managed to do this for a single column using this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;database=studentsresults1"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        mysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from studentsresults1.courses"
        SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, mysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = SQLcmd
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)


        mysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        mysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try


End Sub
```

How can i do this for multiple columns? Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you want to fill the combo with all the data from the columns that you said of the table Marks, right?

One way (really ugly but functional) is to repeat that for the rest of the columns, execute another SQL for another column and add the results that way.

A cleaner way would be loop all the cells:

```
Private Sub GetCourses()
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT OOPVB,DataComms,ModelsDB,MAB,OB, CF FROM marks")
    If SQL.RecordCount > 0 Then
        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
            For Each c in r.ItemArray
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(c.Value)
            Next
        Next
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    ElseIf SQL.Exception <> "" Then
        MsgBox(SQL.Exception)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this, its not working "Public member 'Value' on type 'Integer' not found.".

Comment: My bad, remove the ".value" on "ComboBox1.Items.Add(c.Value)"